# ORDS: Removing escaping char from json in ORDS OUT param

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-ords

I am using the OUT parameter in the ORDS parameters to send a response which is already in JSON and this stored as CLOB in the DB. When I send this out in the response from the ORDS, ORDS is actually adding lot of back spaces to the response.
Can someone help me to understand how I can remove the escaping chars here(all the backslashes). I had tried a different approach explained by Jeff in another thread to try to use an alias for the `JSON` key, but it did not work for me.
Over here I have mentioned the response as OUT parameter in my code.
eg payload:

```
{
    "response": "{\n\"Order\":{\n\"OriginalShipmentID\":1\n,\"orderNumber\":1\n,\"orgID\":1\n,\"orderShipmentNumber\":1\n,\"oracleShipSet\":\"1\"\n,\"OeHeaderId\":1\n,\"GsHeaderId\":1\n,\"CustomerPoNumber\":\"1\"\n,\"PaymentTerms\":1\n,\"FreightTerms\":\"PAID\"\n,\"CurrencyCode\":\"USD\"\n,\"BillToSiteUseID\":1\n,\"ShipToSiteUseID\":1\n,\"SalesChannel\":\"DIRECT\"\n,\"HeaderKeyCode\":\"1 1\"\n,\"OrigSysDocumentRef\":\"1\"\n,\"OrderTypeCode\":\"XYZ yXYZ\"\n,\"OrderTypeID\":1\n,\"SalesRepID\":-3\n,\"IsAtgOrder\":\"N\"\n,\"OrderSource\":\"MCP\"\n,\"OdiDocSet\":\"PO\"\n,\"CsServiceSymbol\":\"XYZ\"\n,\"CsServiceFriendlyName\":\"XYZ\"\n,\"CsShipper\":\"NDC_MX\"\n,\"GsShipToAddressID\":1\n,\"GsBillFrtAddressID\":-1\n,\"BillingMethod\":\"DoNotBillFreight\"\n,\"ReasonForNoInvoice\":\"NA\"\n,\"ShippedBy\":\"NA\"\n,\"ManifestID\":1771748\n,\"IsVoided\":\"N\"\n,\"CustomerNumber\":\"1\"\n,\"OrderLines\":[\n]\n,\"HeaderShortNotes\":{\n}\n}\n}\n"
}
```

Some more details:

```
SELECT get_json ( :ordernumber,
                  :warehouseid,
                  :shipset,
                  :ordershipmentno,
                  :gsshipmentid,
                  :countrycode,
                  :shipperid,
                  :fromcurrency,
                  :tocurrency,
                  :groupid,
                  :optionvalues,
                  :linehaul,
                  :servicename,
                  :sigid,
                  :lineid,
                  :customerid) "{}Order"
          INTO l_response_clob                                   
          FROM DUAL;
```

This function returns a CLOB with a JSON format data and `l_response_clob` is defined as STRING output parameter on the ORDS.
Essentially, I want to stop ORDS from again converting JSON to JSON.
Been banging head over this from some time but can't seem to make it work.
Thanks for the help I can get here.

Comment: I specifically want the source_type to be plsql/block since I want some logic to execute in the ORDS source code as well.

Comment: if you have it return as a BLOB we won't touch the JSON doc returned, it'll be FASTER as well from the DB side as there won't be any charset conversion

Comment: thanks a lot Jeff! I made it work by simply doing htp.p method call instead of sending the response in a OUT param.

Comment: yeah a couple diff things you could do here, like create a function to get the json, use the media resource, but also put your app logic in that function...but i think you chose the cleaner way

Comment: yep. Thanks for the prompt help Jeff :) ORDS is really versatile and every time I think I know enough, there is something new around the corner.